# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.int' is not mapped

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am using flask_restful for my project, I am trying to delete an entry, but unable to do it.
Following is the end point implementation:

```
def delete_from_db(self, emp_no):
    db.session.delete(emp_no)
    db.session.commit()

class DeleteEmployee(Resource):
    @marshal_with({
        'message': fields.String
    })
    def delete(self, employee_id: int):
        employee = db.get_or_404(
            Employees, employee_id,
            description='Employee Not Found'
        )
        employee.delete_from_db(emp_no=employee_id)
        return {
            'message': 'Employee Deleted successfully.'
        }
```

If I execute end point, , which is like that:

```
{{base_URL}}/employee/3
```

I am getting following response:

```
  File "/Users/tp/.pyenv/versions/3.7.13/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3414, in delete
    raise exc.UnmappedInstanceError(instance) from err
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.int' is not mapped
```

If comment the line of `employee.delete_from_db(emp_no=employee_id)`, it will works fine, but it does not delete record from database.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete data, pass the model object to [db.session.delete()](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/queries/#insert-update-delete).

```py
@marshal_with({
    'message': fields.String
})
def delete(self, employee_id: int):
    employee = db.get_or_404(
        Employees, employee_id,
        description='Employee Not Found'
    )
    db.session.delete(employee)
    db.session.commit()
    return {
        'message': 'Employee Deleted successfully.'
    }
```

In your case, with the instance method, it is possible to simply pass `self`.

```py
def delete_from_db(self):
    db.session.delete(self)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Bingo.. It worked... Man, you are becoming life saver for me :).. I don't know if it helps, but We need to connect out side of this..

Comment: @qatesterbecomingprogrammer We can do it. Do you have Discord?